# How to use eslint to format my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, eslint, js-beautify

I'm using vim as my editor, I use eslint for linting javascript code. Before, I use `js-beautify` for formatting js code. But recently I found that eslint has a `--fix` option, which can fix normal coding style issue violate eslint rules.

I also find this [post](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/auto-fixing-formatting-your-javascript-with-eslint/) which suggests use eslint for code formatting. I feel it's a great idea, because I find it's kind of redundant to have both eslint and js-beautify. Since eslint can already detects all my coding style issues, why can't it do format for me?

there's also one drawback to have both js-beautify and eslint, that I need to adjust js-beautify to be in accordance with eslint rules. This is completely unnecessary.

But when I use eslint --fix to js file, it only do some fixing like: insert semicolon, add some space where necessary. But if my code is compressed, it won't format it nicely to human readable format.

How can I make eslint do code format as js-beautify does?

Comment: *"But if my code is compressed, it won't format it nicely to human readable format."* - Why is your code compressed? It's fine (good, even) to minify your code for *deployment* purposes, but you should be *writing* and *maintaining* it in a human-readable format.

Comment: If you look at the list of [ESLint rules](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/), you'll see that only some rules can be fixed automatically with `---fix`.

Comment: @nnnnnn, well, I don't mean to format compressed file, it's just easier to test if eslint --fix will format them to separate lines nicely. using compressed file just for easy testing

Answer (score 3):

I didn't really make eslint format code. But a trick can be used is to pipe the result of `js-beautify` to `eslint --fix`. Thus multiple statements on same line will be formatted by js-beautify and the result will be sent to eslint --fix to fix normal style issues, in the end, you get the formatted and fixed version of code.

Answer (score 0):

Not all rules can be automatically fixed.  Sometimes, it's important for a human to decide how to correct a problem.  These rules won't be fixed for you.

Other rules, like trailing commas, can be safely fixed automatically, and are applied with `--fix`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What I meant to do is use eslint as a code formatter as well. e.g. if several statements on the same line, they'll be formatted to separate lines. if code is not well indented, it'll indent the code nicely. Just want to find a way to tell eslint to do such format job according to my eslint configuration.